# создаются лишние <br> и не удаляются

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```js
   function addBr() {
        if ($(window).width()<=750) {
            $('.journal img').each(function () {

                if ($(this).not('br')) {
                    $(this).after('<br>');
                    alert('<br> созданы');
                }
                else {
                    return false;
               }
        })
    }

    else {
        $('.journal').each().remove('br');
    }
}
    
$(window).load(addBr);
$(window).resize(addBr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="journal">
<p><span>1</span><img src="img/file1.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

 <div class="journal">
<p><span>2</span><img src="img/file2.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

 <div class="journal">
<p><span>3</span><img src="img/file3.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>
```

помогите разобраться, почему при каждом изменении размера окна, 
 создаются снова и снова. и при изменения окна большую от 750px сторону 
 не удаляется

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать-то? Зачем вам вставлять `<br>` при меньше 750?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вы неправильно проверяли на следующий элемент. Вам нужно жестко проверять, `<br>` ли следующий элемент: `$(this).next().prop("tagName") !== "BR"`.

Во-вторых, в документации есть примеры по [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Туда пребуется передать функцию и удалять элементы.

В-третьих, я не понимаю зачем вам вообще такой солюшн.

Вот конкретно решение по вашему вопросу:

```js
function addBr() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 750) {
    $('.journal img').each(function() {
      if ($(this).next().prop("tagName") !== "BR") {
        $(this).after('<br>');
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('.journal br').each(function() {
      $(this).remove()
    });
  }
}

$(window).load(addBr);
$(window).resize(addBr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="journal">
  <p><span>1</span><img src="img/file1.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

<div class="journal">
  <p><span>2</span><img src="img/file2.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

<div class="journal">
  <p><span>3</span><img src="img/file3.png" alt=""> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>
```

Как вариант с [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```css
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .hide-large {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="journal">
  <p><span>1</span><img src="img/file1.png" alt=""><br class="hide-large"> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

<div class="journal">
  <p><span>2</span><img src="img/file2.png" alt=""><br class="hide-large"> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>

<div class="journal">
  <p><span>3</span><img src="img/file3.png" alt=""><br class="hide-large"> учебных журнала в месяц</p>
</div>
```